# Column references another table but reference may have more than one value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I am trying to set up a database design with assets which have a number of distinct IDs, for example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS assets (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
  rl_id INT NOT NULL,
  unique_id VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  UNIQUE(rl_id, unique_id)
);
INSERT INTO assets (rl_id, unique_id) VALUES (3894, 3894); -- a spanish language movie
INSERT INTO assets (rl_id, unique_id) VALUES (3894, '3894dubEN'); -- english dub of that movie
INSERT INTO assets (rl_id, unique_id) VALUES (3894, '3894dubFR'); -- french dub of that movie
```

So this table describes an asset which has both an `rl_id` and a `unique_id`. In my database, multiple assets may have the same `rl_id`. The `unique_id` may be the same as the `rl_id` or it may be different.

However, as long as two items have the same `rl_id`, they share many of the same data.
Although the movie is dubbed into different languages, for example, both the dubs have the same actors. Here are some other tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  speaking_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people_assets_map (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  person_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES people(id),
  rl_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES assets(rl_id),
);
```

However, because I don't have a unique constraint on the asset's `rl_id`, I get the error about `there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "assets"`.

I am wondering what the best solution for this is. This data structure is something we have been using in other places, and we are just formalizing it into SQL, so I don't want to change it. I wonder if there's a way to create a generated table or a view that has all the unique `rl_id`s? I can think of a couple solutions (make a trigger where every time there's a new asset, we upsert its `rl_id`s into an `asset_rl_ids` table?), but most of them feel clunky -- wondering what the best practice is for a situation like this.

Comment: Why not have a separate table to store unique `rl_id`s? That would also improve the referential integrity of the `assets` table…

Comment: *so I don't want to change it* - You've got a design flaw that will complicate everything you do going forward. Hacking a way around the issue isn't going to change that, and you simply need to bite the bullet and make the fix. If you don't, you (and everyone else that works with the data) will regret it, and you're going to end up doing it anyway.

Comment: @GMB This is what I ended up doing actually!

Comment: @KenWhite I meant that I can't change the "there may be multiple items with the same RL_ID" issue, not that this table structure is set in stone.

Comment: You're going to have to fix the *multiple items with the same RI_ID* issue as well. It's a problem caused by a poor DB design, and that design is going to need to be fixed. I'm  not saying that because everyone else does - I've been there, done that, and have a drawer full of the T-shirts, both that I earned years ago and those I've gained fixing other people's mistakes since. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Ahhh, I get you. It's one of those situations where legal hands a problem down to us (rl_ids represent contracts) and we have been dealing with it in a variety of ways with a very small team, and now we have three-year-old data to migrate out of a system that was built for a completely different type of problem. rip to us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rids (
  rid INT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS assets (
  id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
  rid INT REFERENCES rids ON DELETE CASCADE,
  season_rid INT REFERENCES rids ON DELETE SET NULL,
  series_rid INT REFERENCES rids ON DELETE SET NULL,
  uqid VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_into_rlids() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO rids (id) VALUES (NEW.rid)
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER rids_insert_id BEFORE INSERT ON assets
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_into_rlids();
```

Solves my problem because now I can reference the `rids` table when I need that particular ID but I don't have to manually put things in there, it'll happen automatically when I insert something into my `assets` table.

Comment: FWIW, I tried creating a view instead of your rids table but found that I couldn't, at least in Postgres, create a foreign key reference to a view.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you can't change the data structure but the traditional way of doing this would be to put a table between people and people_assets_map. This table would contain the rl_id. Each person would be related to that one rl_id and each rl_id could relate to multiple records in people_assets_map. You would also add any details that are rl_id-specific to this table.